# Decrypting s/mime messages in p7m format with OpenSSL

Tags: objective-c, openssl, pkcs#7

I'm trying to decrypt p7m with OpenSSL but I cannot go through the error in the following part of the code:

```
PKCS7 *p7 = NULL;

in = BIO_new_file(convertedResourcePath, "r");

    if (in) {
        NSLog(@"opening p7m file");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"cannot found p7m file");

    out = BIO_new_file(convertedDecrFilePath, "w");

    if (out) {
        NSLog(@"file for decription has been created");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"failed to create decription file");


    p7 = SMIME_read_PKCS7(in, NULL);

if (p7) {
        NSLog(@"start reading p7m file");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"cannot read p7m file");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

 if (PKCS7_decrypt(p7, pkey, cert, out, 0)) {
        NSLog(@"file decrypted sucessfully!");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"cannot decrypt file");
```

I got the following in output:

> opening p7m file 2013-07-22 12:45:22.951 smimePrototype[10827:c07]
>   file for decription has been created 2013-07-22 12:45:22.952
>   smimePrototype[10827:c07] cannot read p7m file
>   2900150892:error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no
>   content type:asn_mime.c:451:
>   2013-07-22 12:45:22.953 smimePrototype[10827:c07] cannot decrypt file

Looking for your help, maybe p7 variable can be initialized in other way?

Comment: Is your p7m binary encoded or base64? SMIME_read_PKCS7 can only handle base64. See the BUGS section of http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/SMIME_read_PKCS7.html

Comment: Paul, thank you for your answer. It looks like that p7m is encoded in base64, maybe SMiME_read_PKCS7 method does not support p7m containers?

Also I tried use the following function instead of SMIME_read_pKCS7: 
p7=d2i_PKCS7_bio(in,NULL);

It works but after the p7 is decrypted output contains a lot of system data

Comment: Maybe try PEM_read_bio_PKCS7?

Comment: Paul, looks like in my case using p7=d2i_PKCS7_bio(in,NULL); method it the right decision, now output just should be parsed (e.g. with mimetic or something similar). Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to use

```
p7=d2i_PKCS7_bio(in,NULL);
```

instead of

```
p7 = SMIME_read_PKCS7(in, NULL);
```

and it works great.

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: You deserve a medal.