# How to decrypt smime.p7m file in DER format using OpenSSL in C code.

Tags: encryption, openssl, pkcs#7, der

I am trying to decrypt emails using openssl.

I am getting smime.p7m file from the server. But it is in DER format.

I can decrypt this file using command prompt, with the command

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in openssl_working_smime.p7m -inform DER -inkey mycert.pem > dec_mail.eml
```

But now I want to do this using C code.

Right now I am trying to do using -

```
SMIME_read_PKCS7()
```

But this returns null with

```
SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:asn_mime.c:451:
```

error

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decrypting s/mime messages in p7m format with OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784735/decrypting-s-mime-messages-in-p7m-format-with-openssl)